# Youtube API - remove bottom-right youtube logo in the IFrame Player API method?

Tags: javascript, html, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

So If I use the normal tag iframe to embed youtube to website, I can remove youtube's logo on the bottom-right by use  modestbranding=1 after VideoID 
like this

```
 <iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ADgeqLVR6EY?modestbranding=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

but if I use the IFrame Player API methd  I don't know how to remove youtube logo, I put the modestbranding=1 after VideoID but it did not work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="player"></div>

    <script>

      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '360', 
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'QyhrOruvT1c?modestbranding=1' //it did not remove logo. :(
        });
      }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In YT player parameters can't be passed in videoId, use `playerVars` for that

```
player = new YT.Player('player', {
   height: '360', 
   width: '640',
   videoId: 'QyhrOruvT1c',
   playerVars: {'modestbranding':1} // <-- add this
});
```